# How do i migrate objc [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(abc)] to swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm trying to migrate my objc code to swift.

Here I'm trying to send my button action method as NSValue
`[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(abc)]`

This can then be converted to a pointer using
`[NSValue pointer]` method, after which I can call my button action method using
`[id performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` method.

My question is how do I do the same thing on swift, since swift doesn't preemptively use pointers.

Any suggestion will be helpful, Thank you.

Comment: Swift also doesn’t use selectors. You can just pass a function reference or an actual closure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will check it out.

Comment: Yep - you need a closure for this, that is the Swifty way.

Comment: Cool, Thank you.